# Derivate from rest of the division

Tags: math, calculus

Rest of division `(f(x) mod g(x) = h(x))` I mean for example `(3.15 mod 3.14 = 0.01).`

In General what are Derivatives of that kind of function ?

```
dh(x)/dx
dh(x)/df(x)
dh(x)/dg(x)
```

Comment: What does this have to do with computer programming? Wwhat work have you done on this problem so far, and just where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on the Mathematics Stack Exchange site and because the questioner has shown no work of his own.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about differentiation / calculus / [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

As

```
h(x) = f(x) - (f(x) div g(x)) * g(x)
```

you will need to define a derivative for the integer-valued function `f(x) div g(x)`. Depending on what you really had in mind, this involves the Dirac delta distribution.

Comment: thank you, I will use that formula to calculate needed derivatives, been long since I have done any math